# Java Pattern matching group value containing parantheses

Tags: java, regex, pcre

I am trying to group a string expression into three parts using Regex . It works for most cases and getting stuck for one case .

Regex

```
([\\w.]+?)(:|<|>|<=|>=|%|-|\\(\\))([\\w\\s,.:-]+?)\\|
```

Code :

```
private SearchCriteria validateFilterPattern(String filter) {
        final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("([\\w.]+?)(:|<|>|<=|>=|%|-|\\(\\))([\\w\\s,.:-]+?)\\|");
        Matcher m = pattern.matcher(filter + "|");
        if (m.find()) {
            return SearchCriteria.builder().key(m.group(1)).operator(m.group(2)).value(m.group(3)).build();
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException(ErrorMessage.FILTER_FORMAT_INVALID, filter);
        }
    }
```

Input is having pattern key:value . The above code is using the regex and grouping the input expression into three parts : key ,operator and value . Operators can be : , > , < , >= , <= , * , ~ , () , %
Keys can be any word , value can contain word , letters , dots , colon,some special characters and brackets.

I am able to match following and group it into three parts.

```
regulatory:Section 740.17 Mass Market
regulatory:Section 740.17
```

The above two inputs segregate into groups like

```
key {regulatory} , operator {:} , value {Section 740.17 Mass Market}
key {regulatory} , operator {:} , value {Section 740.17}
```

But not able to group it for inputs where value contains brackets.

```
regulatory:Section 740.17(b)(1) Mass Market
regulatory()Section 740.17(b)(1) Mass Market
```

The above should segregate into groups like

```
key {regulatory} , operator {:} , value {Section 740.17(b)(1) Mass Market}
key {regulatory} , operator {()} , value {Section 740.17(b)(1) Mass Market}
```

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire I have changed my question to add more clarity into what I am trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

Able to solve it by using below regex

```
"([\\w.]+?)(:|<|>|<=|>=|%|-|\\(\\))([\\w\\s,.:\\(\\)-]+?)\\|"
```